# Send data from php to chart with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

i'm new in using chart.js and php. I want to send array data from model to my chart with ajax, because we can't write ph script in javascript, of course.

this is my model

```
class Chart_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getJK()
    {
        return $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(IF(jk='Laki-laki',1,0)) AS jumlah_pria, SUM(IF(jk='Perempuan',1,0)) AS jumlah_perempuan FROM penduduk")->row_array();
    }
}
```

and this is my chart.js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("jenisKelamin");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Perempuan", "Laki-laki"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: ['#1cc88a', '#4e73df'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#17a673', '#2e59d9'],
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
        }],
    }
});
```

How can i send row array data to the chart using ajax? i have googling but many of it using old chart.js syntax, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to use AJAX requests to fetch the data and show it on your webpage. In your Javascript file, you request data in a JSON format, which can then be processed by your js script.

I found a tutorial for this at https://phppot.com/php/creating-dynamic-data-graph-using-php-and-chart-js/, that uses the JQuery $.post() method.